# using a tee inside a .desktop file for debug logging

Tags: .desktop, tee

How do I write a .desktop file that includes a tee?

Normally I start my debug logging from terminal, using a .sh like the below:

```
sudo ./start-ds.sh 2>&1 | tee output.log
```

I have to go into hospital and I want to continue the testing whilst I am in so I want my partner to simply double click the desktop icon to start it.

How do I write a .desktop file that will start the app and also have it start a debug log file?

current start-ds.desktop file is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=Start ds
Exec=/home/agx/ds/start-ds.sh
```

current .sh file is:

```
#!/bin/bash

export gst_debug=3

$(/home/agx/ds/ds-app -c /home/agx/ds/app-config.txt)

exit 0
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Why are you wrapping the command inside a command substitution `$(...)`? Do you want the output to be tee'd only when run from the .desktop file, or when the shell script is run directly as well? Do you want errors to be tee'd to the log file, or just standard output?

Comment: HI, I was told to wrap it in $(....) by an "expert"

I noticed that I missed out the export debug line also, sorry - it must the the stress.

The "export gst_debug=3" should log all of the error messages so I think this means I just want the standard output.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I simply created a second .sh

```
#!/bin/bash
$(sudo ./start-ds.sh 2>&1 | tee output.log)
exit 0
```

then modified the .desktop to run that one and it, in turn, starts the original .sh with logging